# Ionic Angular - FileReader failed onloadend on Android device but successful with >ionic serve (browser)

Tags: android, angular, android-studio, ionic-framework

The code below works running the app through >ionic serve. Click on **select** will pop up a file selection box, select the image and everything else works.  However when I debug with Android Studio and run it on my Android phone, the reader.onloaded never triggered. I can't verify but i believe event.target.files was empty as well after I selected several photos on the phone and proceed.  I had READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission added in AndroidManifest.xml.

```
---- HTML ----
<a (click)="fileInput.click()">select</a>
<input #fileInput style='display: none' type="file" accept="image/jpeg" multiple (change)="selectFiles($event)" />


--- Angular ----

    selectFiles(event: any): void {
        this.message = [];
        this.progressInfos = [];
        this.selectedFiles = event.target.files;

        if (this.selectedFiles && this.selectedFiles[0]) {
            const numberOfFiles = this.selectedFiles.length;
            if (numberOfFiles > 8){
                alert("Max 8 images");
            }else{
                for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onloadend = (e: any) => {

                        const image = new Image();
                        image.src = e.target.result;
                        image.onload = () => {
                            let index = this.previews.findIndex(preview=>preview.img === '');
                            this.previews[index] = {img:e.target.result, width:image.width, height:image.height, data:this.selectedFiles[i], inProgress: false, progress: 0, id: null};
                            this.fileSelectTrigger.notify(true);
                        };
                    };
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFiles[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Further debuging shows that the file loaded from Mobile has invalid lastModified date
lastModified: -11644473600000
lastModifiedDate: Mon Jan 01 1601 09:39:52 GMT+0939 (Australian Eastern Daylight Time) while on browser it is showing correct date

Comment: Invalid lastModified date appears on Huawei P30, S21U shows a correct lastModified date  however the problem still exist. reader.onloadend never triggered.